# An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, windows-server-2008

There is nasty issue that doesn't make me sleep freely. We have an ASP.NET website and WCF server that serves that site. After some time period an error is raising telling that

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system
> lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
> x.x.x.x:8731 in
>
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)

And after that our site can't connect to service.

This bundle (site+service) was working fine on Windows Server 2003, but then we moved it onto our new Windows Server 2008 standard it becomes fail after some time period.

We had some tcp checkings in our service. Service just opens connection to another hosts and if connection was successful service think that everything is right and continue do other business logic. When we cut off this checking it seems like server began to fall more rarely but this error still getting us frustrated.

I have faced with possible suggestion to arrange `MaxUserPort` option in registry, but seems like this parameter in Win2008 has another meaning than in Win2003, and it's OK.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?